# Setting redis configuration options in sidekiq container

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I just ran a `docker-compose build` on my latest docker container and I noticed that sidekiq is now generating this line, repetitively:

```
sidekiq_1   | `Redis#exists(key)` will return an Integer in redis-rb 4.3. `exists?` returns a boolean, you should use it instead. To opt-in to the new behavior now you can set Redis.exists_returns_integer =  true. To disable this message and keep the current (boolean) behaviour of 'exists' you can set `Redis.exists_returns_integer = false`, but this option will be removed in 5.0. (/usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/launcher.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in ❤')
```

Where exactly do I set this setting? I tried to create an initializer, but I'm sure I'm doing this wrong:

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
redis_conn = proc {
  Redis.exists_returns_integer =  true
}

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 5, &redis_conn)
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 25, &redis_conn)
end
```

The container failed with this error when trying to use the code from the initializer above:

```
sidekiq_1   | 2020-06-17T02:42:21.743Z pid=1 tid=gshym9ynx INFO: Booted Rails 5.2.4 application in development environment
sidekiq_1   | 2020-06-17T02:42:21.743Z pid=1 tid=gshym9ynx INFO: Running in ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x86_64-linux]
sidekiq_1   | 2020-06-17T02:42:21.743Z pid=1 tid=gshym9ynx INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
sidekiq_1   | 2020-06-17T02:42:21.743Z pid=1 tid=gshym9ynx INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: https://sidekiq.org
sidekiq_1   | undefined method `info' for true:TrueClass
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:118:in `block in redis_info'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:97:in `block in redis'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in with'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:62:in `handle_interrupt'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:62:in `block in with'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:59:in `handle_interrupt'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/connection_pool-2.2.3/lib/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:94:in `redis'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:112:in `redis_info'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:61:in `run'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/bin/sidekiq:31:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
sidekiq_1   | /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
test_sidekiq_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add an initializer file redis.rb to silence the warning.

```
if Gem::Version.new(Sidekiq::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('6.1')
  Redis.exists_returns_integer = true
else
  raise 'Time to remove Redis.exists_returns_integer: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4591'
end
```

credits: https://github.com/DFE-Digital/apply-for-postgraduate-teacher-training/pull/2275/files/16d2ad7ae053247760cf3905cdbacfdf4ec4b7ea

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this. Changing the way a library returns a value to another library that doesn't know how to handle it yet can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue on the sidekiq github related to this issue.

You can see it here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4591

Basically, the redis gem made a change that, going forward, will cause different behavior when using a certain method. There's nothing you can do to suppress this message until Sidekiq 6.1 comes out other than temporarily downgrade the version of the redis gem you're using.

I currently have this in my Gemfile to avoid getting spammed with this message.

```
gem 'redis', '4.1.4'
```

The problem isn't anything you're doing, it's the libraries you're using.